# Does Christianity have any connections to the Hinduism?

Tags: comparative-religion, other-religions, hinduism

Islam and Christianity has same roots and also some names in Bible can also be heard in Quran.

What about Christianity connection with Hinduism?

Because so many pastors claiming that connection exists, but in evil way.

Example: Hindu goddesses are considered as Satans etc.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Your question, though a good one, is probably not answerable here because there are so many different Christian denominations and perspectives that will view this question differently, so that there is no objective answer to the question. I you want the view of a particular denomination, that would be answerable here.

Comment: Hinduism *does* have some somewhat well-known connections to European polytheism (e.g. Zeus, Thor, etc.) via the religion of the Proto-Indo-European speaking peoples.

Comment: Is this a rant or a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard any pastors claim anything evil about Hinduism and it’s doubtful many do. The ones that may are obviously not reputable and you should withdraw your membership.

As far as connections between the Judaic faiths and those in the subcontinent, it’s difficult to state.

There are legends in India and Nepal that Christ visited the region in trade missions between the ages of 12 and 30. Some are written in Sanskrit but how these accounts are verifiable I couldn’t imagine. This wouldn’t be exactly a Hindu connection as much as it would be a Buddhist connection, but it might be a start for your idea. There are several books on the topic.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site. If you stick around you may also want to [register an account](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) here.

Answer (score 2):

Christianity is a monotheistic religion. Christians believe and teach that any other gods are false gods set up by and for Satan himself. This is the reason why a pastor may speak against Shiva, Vishnu etc. As such Christianity has no theological ties as Hinduism is polytheistic while Christianity is not.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 0):

**Does Christianity have any connections to the Hinduism?**

Christianity is a monotheistic religion in that it believes in one God. Hinduism can also be a monotheistic religion, but inherits religious concepts spanning monotheism, polytheism, panentheism, pantheism, monism, and atheism!

One possible connection that Hinduism has with Christianity would be through the three **Wise Men**. There is no uniform consensus in Christianity as to where the **Three Kings of Orient** were from.

In the revelations of Catherine Emmerich, she notes that one of them was baptized by [St. Thomas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_the_Apostle) after the Crucifixion of Jesus. Traditionally St. Thomas the Apostle evangelized the people of India.

> [**Hinduism**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotheism)
>
> As an old religion, Hinduism inherits religious concepts spanning monotheism, polytheism, panentheism, pantheism, monism, and atheism among others; and its concept of God is complex and depends upon each individual and the tradition and philosophy followed.
>
> Hindu views are broad and range from monism, through pantheism and panentheism (alternatively called monistic theism by some scholars) to monotheism and even atheism. Hinduism cannot be said to be purely polytheistic. Hindu religious leaders have repeatedly stressed that while God's forms are many and the ways to communicate with him are many, God is one. The puja of the murti is a way to communicate with the abstract one god (Brahman) which creates, sustains and dissolves creation.

One possible connection that Hinduism may have with Christianity is through the three *Wise Men** that came from the orient. According to the revelations of [Catherine Emmerich](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Catherine_Emmerich), the **Three Kings of Orient** came from different cities in the East and that [St. Thomas the Apostle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_the_Apostle) baptized on of them after he Crucifixion of Jesus. Traditionally, St. Thomas preached and evangelized the people of India.

> The Three Kings and the ancients acted, each one in his own family, like the father of the house, cut­ting up the food and helping it around. The carved birds and little loaves were laid on small dishes, or plates, which stood upon little feet, and passed around; and in the same way, the cups were filled and handed to each one to drink. The lowest among the servants, of whom some were Moors, reclined on the bare earth. They appeared to be slaves. The sim­plicity,Mensor, the brownish, was a Chaldean. His city, whose name sounded to me something like Acajaja, was surrounded by a river, and appeared to be built on an island. Mensor spent most of his time in the fields with his herds. **After the death of Christ, he was baptized by St. Thomas**, and named Leander. Seir, the brown, on that very Christmas night stood prepared at Mensor's for the expedition. He and his race were the only ones so brown, but they had red lips. The other people in the neighborhood were white. Seir had the baptism of desire. He was not living at the time of Jesus' journey to the country of the Kings. Theokeno was from Media, a country more to the north. It lay like a strip of land further toward the interior and between two seas. Theokeno dwelt in his own city; its name I have forgotten. It consisted of tents erected on stone foundations. He was the wealthiest of the three. He might, I think, have taken a more direct route to Bethlehem, but in order to join the others he made a circuitous one. I think that he had even to pass near Babylon in order to come up with them. He also was baptized by St. Thomas and named Leo. The names Caspar, Melchior, and Balthasar were given to the kings, because they so well suited them, for Caspar means "He is won by love"; Melchior, "He is so coaxing, so insinuating, he uses so much address, he approaches one so gently"; Balthasar, "With his whole will, he accomplishes the will of God."
>
> From Mensor's city, Seir dwelt at the distance of a three days' journey, each day counting twelve hours; and Theokeno further on, at a distance of five such days. Mensor and Seir were together when they saw in the stars the vision of the birth of Jesus, and both  set out on the following day with their respective caravans. Theokeno, also, had the same vision in his own home, and he hurried to join the other two. Their journey to Bethlehem was about seven hundred and some odd hours. In the odd number, six occurs. It was a journey of about sixty days, each day twelve hours long; but they accomplished it in thirty-three days, on account of the great speed of their camels, and because they often travelled day and night. - [ife of Jesus Christ by Anne Catherine Emmerich
> 1774-1824](https://tandfspi.org/ACE_vol_01/ACE_1_0241_out.html#ACE_1_0000185)

Regardless if there is a real connection or not between these two religions, there are some believe that Jesus went toIndia during his hidden years or from the time he was 13 through 30. It seems more like a [Ripley’s Believe It or Not](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripley%27s_Believe_It_or_Not!) moment!

During the [unknown years of Jesus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknown_years_of_Jesus) nothing is really historically known as to what Jesus actually did is impossible to confirm!

Answer (score -2):

That Hindu goddesses are satanic is sheer nonsense.

Hinduism is the only classical civilisation to survive in modern times. The Babylonian, the Egyptian, the Greek and the Roman did not survive. To my mind, it's startling that those who study classics leave this civilisation to one side, whereas one might think, that this is a living and breathing example of what they study, would make it of immediate interest. But then again, that's probably as Plato already suggested, Hellenic Eurocentrism for you...

For example, Lakhsmi, being the goddess of wealth and wisdom, is akin to that of the muses, and in particular, Athena, the Greek goddess of wisdom and the patron goddess of Ancient Athens; she does have a darker kin, Kali, the goddess of wrath and destruction; but then again, we have the Greek goddess Artemis; who, in her Roman aspect, is Diana, was also a huntress.

When faced with the theology of monotheism, polytheism began to go adrift and finally began to be absorbed into Christianity and Islam in various ways. For example, Christmas, or Christs Mass, was originally a pagan custom - hence all the 'pagan' feasting, when the actual religious ceremony, is rather solemn, and sublime for that.

Hinduism has many philosophies, but one predominant amongst it, is Vedantism, which again speaks of a unitary divine reality, which the gods, and the goddesses, and this world, is simply a manifestation. Hence, in a way, it is monotheistic.

The European and Indic languages are related and are said to be of the Indo-Aryan family. Aryan, here, meaning from Iran, that is Persia. Given all this, it would be of no surprise to find that much in common in our religious thinking. I mean by 'our' from India, the Middle East, and Europe, that is in the Eurasian landmass.

For example, going by language,  *Devi*, refers to the mother goddess in Hinduism; its etymologically root *dev-*, means *a shining one*, and is cognate to the Greek *dios*, 'divine', and to Zeus, and to *Deus* in Latin.

It's also notable that in old Zoroastrian, in their religious scriptures, *the Gathas*, mention the *daevas*; they are the gods to be rejected because they promote chaos and disorder.